# Mappear DTO con class[]

Tags: java, spring-boot

tengo un cliente

```
public OrderDTO[] findAllOrders() throws OrderGetException {
        try {
            return restTemplate.exchange(Url + "list", HttpMethod.GET,null, OrderDTO[].class).getBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error to get orders no paging");
            throw new OrderGetException(e);
        }
    }
```

y me esta retornando un [], el problema es que este tipo no lo puedo mapear, necesito crear un DTO nuevo para ponerle mas valores a este resultado mezclando con otro endpoint, pero a la hora de mapear el tipo [] no me permite hacerlo

Actualmente este es mi mapper:

```
@Component
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", implementationName = "OrderDTOMapperImpl", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface OrderMapper {
    OrderDTO[] orderToAllOrders (OrderDTO[] order);
}
```

este mi servicio:

```
public OrderDTO[] getOrders() throws OrderGetException {
        OrderDTO[] responseListOrders = orderClient.findAllOrders();
        OrderDTO[] orderDTO = orderMapper.orderToAllOrders(responseListOrders);
        return orderDTO;
    }
```

Y finalmente el controlador:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/list", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public OrderDTO[] getOrders() throws Exception {
        return orderService.getAllOrders();
    }
```

La idea es tomar lo que me da el cliente e incluirle unos campos nuevos, pero el tipo [] no lo permite, podrían por favor darme una mano para encontrar la mejor solución. Gracias